# Google Postmaster Tools DKIM issue

Tags: email, gmail, sendgrid, dkim

Looking at my domain in Google Postmaster Tools, I can seem that the DKIM success rate is 0%. This despite doing tests on any 3rd party platform, such as MX Toolbox, Mail-tester.com and others, confirm the DKIM has been set up correctly. I experience bad IP and domain reputation on this sender, which I am concerned comes from this authentication issue.

Emails are btw. being sent out through whitelabeled SendGrid setup.
Any suggestions?

Thank you
Brdgs
Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by me adding the subdomain (marketing.example.com) to the Postmaster Tools. Adding the top domain (example.com) solved the issue.